# MongoDB & Java DBRef Usage

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

So let’s say I have a patient document in MongoDB. It has things such as first name, last name, etc… I am trying to add to the current document a list of providers (which is another collection, by DBRef, as I am using POJO. How would I append multiple providers in Java to the document?

Comment: For clarity, please edit your question to include at least a "before" example of a doc and and "after update" example.   More help will come your way if you show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is  by just appending to a document like this:

```
Document doc = new Document("user", userObject)
                    .append("providers", providersObject);
```

`providersObject` would be your list of providers.